# Hibernate JPA @ManyToMany Mapping Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I am trying to have a many to many relationship between user and group, so when I save group the user and group information should get saved in user_group table, but  I am getting this error while trying to save Group information,In request I am just passing groupName.

Error

```
2022-11-07 14:45:47.565 ERROR 29066 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`user_group`, CONSTRAINT `FK7k9ade3lqbo483u9vuryxmm34` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", 
    uniqueConstraints = { 
      @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
      @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email") 
    })
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(  name = "user_roles", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
  private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();


  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
          cascade = {
                  CascadeType.PERSIST,
                  CascadeType.MERGE
          },
          mappedBy = "users")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

  public Set<Group> getGroups() {
    return groups;
  }
}
```

Group.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "grp")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String groupName;

    @Column
    private String createdBy;

    public Group(String groupName, String createdBy ) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }


    public Group() {

    }
}
```

GroupController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class GroupController  {


    @Autowired
    GroupRepository groupRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/group")
    public ResponseEntity<Group> createTutorial(@RequestBody Group group, Principal principal) {
        try {
            Set<User> userSet = new HashSet<>();
            Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsername(principal.getName());
            userSet.add(user.get());
            Group group2 = new Group(group.getGroupName(), principal.getName());
            group2.setUsers(userSet);
            Group group1 = groupRepository.save(group2);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(group1, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: degug of controller]

Comment: With `group2.setUsers(userSet);` you seem to add users to the group, but the relation between groups and users is not visible in the source of Group class. Could you please complete the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my database schema which got created by an earlier incorrect JPA model. after dropping and recreating the database it got resolved.